# Print the content of an HTML element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to print the content of an HTML element if the element isn't empty:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("simpleproduct");
            if(x != null){
                var y = x[0].innerHTML;
                alert(y);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is the button that calls the JavaScript function:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">ClickToSee</button>
```

This is a sample HTML element

```
<h5 class="simpleproduct">199.99</h5>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {});

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("simpleproduct");
  if (x != null) {
    var y = x[0].innerHTML;
    alert(y);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">ClickToSee</button>
<h5 class="simpleproduct">199.99</h5>
```

put the function outside of the jquery.ready

Comment: it apears that something is blocking it in my code. because alert did not pop

Comment: Try console.log instead of alert, that way you can see if the code reaches this part or the problem is with alerts

Comment: or you can add the whole file as a snippet so I could see it

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery its as simple as this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#myButton').on('click', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var text = $(".simpleproduct").text();
    alert(text);
}

});
```

```html
<button id="myButton">ClickToSee</button>
<h5 class="simpleproduct">199.99</h5>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: `simpleproduct` selector could be more refined to return only one element based on complete template structure.